# Disable Reminders from a Shared Outlook Calander

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Is there a way to disable reminders from a shared calendar in Outlook while leaving reminders on for other Outlook calendars?

Comment: Reminders are configured per event, generally speaking. What OS? What client? What research have you done prior to asking? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

- If the shared calendar is added as a separate email account in the same profile with your primary account, you can remove it and add it as an additional mailbox1. This way, you will not see the reminders for the shared calendar, but only for your own calendar.
- If the shared calendar is auto-mapped to your account, you can disable the auto-mapping feature and manually open the shared calendar. This way, you will not get the reminders for the shared calendar, but only for your own calendar.
- If you have access to the shared calendar’s account, you can log in to it and turn off the default reminders for all events. This way, no one who shares the calendar will get the reminders, but you can still get the reminders for your own calendar.

A similar thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/596016/how-to-turn-off-calendar-reminders-for-shared-mail

Answer (score 0):

- Open Outlook Webmail
- Select Calendar
- Click drop down next to People’s Calendars
- Select the shared calendar and choose View menu
- From View menu select the gear to launch gear to launch Calendar Settings.
- Choose Shared Calendars and under Calendar Updates un-check the box next to the shared calendar to stop receiving shared calendar events email notifications.
- Click Save.